# I want to list the data I received from Firebase in the Dropdown Menu. Dropdown is unresponsive when I click on the menu. What could be the problem?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu

[App view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZRli.png)

I tried to list the data I received from Firebase in the dropdown menu in the dialog. I don't get any errors in coding, but when clicking the menu it doesn't open. Where am I doing wrong?

```
StatefulBuilder(builder:
    (BuildContext context,
        StateSetter setState) {
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    isDense: true,
    hint: new Text("Proje Seçiniz"),
    value: _selected1,
    onChanged: (newValue) {
      setState(() {
        _selected1 = newValue;
      });

      print(_selected1);
    },
    items: data.map((list) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Image(
                image: NetworkImage(list[
                    "personelResim"])),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10),
                child: Text(
                  list["name"] +
                      " " +
                      list["surname"],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
}),
```

Firebase data retrieval codes

```
List data = [];


var response;

await _firestore.collection("personeller").get().then((data) {
  response = data.docs[0].data();
  data = jsonDecode(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a different usage. I used the question asked here before for the different method.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53297046/19502291)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're changing the `data` that has come as a response, try to:

```
List something = [];


var response;

await _firestore.collection("personeller").get().then((data) {
  response = data.docs[0].data();
  something = jsonDecode(response);
});
```

Let me know if it works, good luck!

Comment: Yes, you are right. overlooked, but my problem is that I cannot convert the data type from Firebase into a String list. and I am getting this error "Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

Comment: @AhmetAydın could you provide the code of `jsonDecod`. I think you have to define the parameter in the method that decode json, as a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved my problem with a different usage. I used the question asked here before for the different method.